# Spring Boot external configuration without ignoring the packaged configuration

Tags: spring-boot

I am developing a Spring Boot JAR application and what I want is for some configuration properties to be found in an external path. I want something like this:

the jar to be located at `/home/myapps/my-spring-boot-app.jar`

the configuration to be located at `/apps/configuration/app/config.properties`

I have set the spring-boot-maven-plugin with layout:ZIP and I have tried with different configurations like `spring.config.location="/apps/configuration/app/"` and `loader.path="/apps/configuration/app/"` and it didn't work.

In some cases, it ignored my external configuration, and in some cases, it ignored my packaged configuration. I don't want to use the Spring Boot defined hierarchy, to have the configuration in `./config/`

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Acording to documentation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html spring.config.location can accept more than one file, so you can try something like this:

`spring.config.location=classpath:/application.properties,/apps/configuration/app/config.properties`

or just directories:
`spring.config.location=classpath:/,/apps/configuration/app/`

Comment: I have listed through hundreds of similar posts yesterday and not one had this suggestion. You my friend, are a life saver!

Comment: Thanks, I'm glad that I could help :)